# Xpath only selecting first instance of element

Tags: java, xpath

I am using `javax.xml.xpath.XPath;` To attempt to parse some `XML`

Sometimes a particular element may appear multiple times, when this happens I want to select all of them.

I have the following `XML` (tag names and values have been changed)

```
<Pearent>
 <a>hello</a>
 <a>world</a>
 <b>bye</b>
</Pearent>
```

I want to get the text value of all a nodes

The results are being inserted directly into a `Java` `HashMap` and then accessed using `Thymeleaf`

if I use the following `xpath` `/Pearent/a`, I get `"hello"`

If I use `/Pearent/a[1]` I get `"hello"`

If I use `/Pearent/a[2]` I get "world"

I have also tried targeting just the `Pearent` node so If I use `/Pearent`
I get `"\n   hello\n    world\n    bye\n"`
(note the the formatting `"\n   "` has been automatically inserted)

I cannot target the pearent node as a solution to my problem because sometimes a `Pearent` node has other child nodes which I don't want.

Interestingly I have tried the same `XML` and `XPath` in an online parser
http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

And I get different results

If I use the `xpath` `/Pearent/a`, I get `<a>hello</a><a>world</a>`

If I use the `xpath` `/Pearent/a[1]`, I get `<a>hello</a>`

If I use the `xpath` `/Pearent/a[2]`, I get `<a>world</a>`

If I use the `xpath` `/Pearent`, I get `<Pearent><a>hello</a><a>world</a><b>bye</b></Pearent>`

I see 2 differences here:

1. The online parser returns whole nodes, my parser only returns the text content of nodes
2. The online parser selects all elements which match, my parser only selects the first element which matches.

My parser function is bellow

My questions are:

- How can I control the formatting which appears to be being inserted when my `xpath` targets a node which has multiple child nodes?
- How can I get the text value of all child nodes as a string (ie for `Xpath` `/Pearent/a` I would want to get `"helloworld"`
- How can I return the results as separate nodes so that i can use a `foreach` loop on them in `Java` (remember I said the results were being passed into a `hashmap` value) or `ThymeLeaf`

### MY XML PARSER CODE

```
public String readValue(String XML , String Xpath) throws Exception{

        final DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory =     DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(Boolean.parseBoolean(propertyConfiguration.getNameSpaceAware()));
    final DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document xml = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(XML)));

    final XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    String retrievedValue = xPath.compile(Xpath).evaluate(xml);

    return retrievedValue;
}
```

---

### THE PARSER FUNCTION IS BEING CALLED BY

```
Map requiredData = new HashMap();
requiredData.put("Title","/Pearent/a");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your `evaulate()` method like below.

You can get all the nodes with tag name `a` using `xpath` and then iterate through the nodes to get text inside tag.

```
NodeList node = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate( "/Pearent/a", xml, XPathConstants.NODESET );

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for ( int i = 0; i < node.getLength(); i++ ) {

    stringBuilder.append( node.item( i ).getTextContent() );    
}

System.out.println( stringBuilder.toString() );
```

**Output:**

helloworld

Comment: That helped a lot
Although i feal i should have been able to achieve the resutlt i wanted just by using Xpath, i dont like having to use Xpath to get what i want and then having to work with Node and NodeList to get the final string output.

Comment: Well, there's a mismatch between the type systems of Java and XPath, and when you mix languages you're always going to have to write messy code to bridge the gaps between different type systems. The best solution to that is to avoid mixing languages - you can probably write the whole application in XSLT or XQuery, and cut out the Java. Also, if you move to XPath 2.0, the type system is richer (for example you can return a sequence of strings rather than a sequence of nodes), which gives you more options.

Answer (score 0):

To get `"helloworld"`, you might use

```
/Pearent/concat(./a[1]/text(), ./a[2]/text())
```

To get `"hello world"`

```
/Pearent/concat(./a[1]/text(), " ", ./a[2]/text())
```

Comment: I have not tried that yet, but that would only work if i know how many identical nodes there will be. 
Unfortunatly i dont have this information. My code could be used to dynamically fetch an XML object from a data set numbered in the millions - most nodes are optional and dont have a fixed number.

Comment: If there are unknown number of `<a>` tags, you can use `/Pearent/string-join(./a/normalize-space(text()), ' ')`

Comment: Your answer and last comment would both require xpath 2.0 (it appears the OP is using 1.0).

Comment: I didn't notice info about `XPath` version... I might miss that from context